# How can I write Clash Parsers with multiple Urls?

Tags: yaml

I wonder how I can write a parser in Clash with multiple URLs.

```
parsers:
  - url: https://wwc.mianhuayun.xyz/api/v1/client/subscribe?token=22f94b503fe9ea96ebfc9419c8a1f82a
    yaml:
      prepend-rules:
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,api.mcneel.com,REJECT
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,rhino3d.com,REJECT
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,feed.rhino3d.work,REJECT
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,api2.enscape3d.com,REJECT
        ...
       

  - url: https://sub.wl-sub1.com/api/v1/client/subscribe?token=8286581d77b7bce8a3278974a8ae5ec7
    yaml:
      prepend-rules:
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,api.mcneel.com,REJECT
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,rhino3d.com,REJECT
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,feed.rhino3d.work,REJECT
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,api2.enscape3d.com,REJECT
        ...
```

As you can see above, I've written parsers with two URLs, but the pretend rules of them are the same, so can I change it like the following:

```
parsers:
  - url: https://wwc.mianhuayun.xyz/api/v1/client/subscribe?token=22f94b503fe9ea96ebfc9419c8a1f82a
  - url: https://sub.wl-sub1.com/api/v1/client/subscribe?token=8286581d77b7bce8a3278974a8ae5ec7
    yaml:
      prepend-rules:
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,api.mcneel.com,REJECT
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,rhino3d.com,REJECT
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,feed.rhino3d.work,REJECT
       - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,api2.enscape3d.com,REJECT
        ...
```

I put the urls together, can I ? Thanks!

I want to get a exactly right answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

First, be careful to hide your URLs.
I assume you want to handle two URLs at the same time with the same rules. After some searching, you can try the following rules:

```
parsers:
  - reg: ^.*$ # 第一个执行的parser
    yaml:
      commands:
        - proxy-groups.⚖️ 负载均衡-散列.proxies=[]proxyNames
        - proxy-groups.0.proxies.0+⚖️ 负载均衡-散列
        - proxy-groups.⚖️ 负载均衡-轮询.proxies=[]proxyNames
        - proxy-groups.0.proxies.0+⚖️ 负载均衡-轮询
      append-proxy-groups:
        - name: ⚖️ 负载均衡-散列
          type: load-balance
          url: 'http://www.google.com/generate_204'
          interval: 300
          strategy: consistent-hashing
        - name: ⚖️ 负载均衡-轮询
          type: load-balance
          url: 'http://www.google.com/generate_204'
          interval: 300
          strategy: round-robin
      prepend-rules:
        - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,website-go-proxy-a.com, ⚖️ 负载均衡-散列
        - DOMAIN-KEYWORD,website-go-proxy-b.com, ⚖️ 负载均衡-散列
```

Works fine for me.
新年快乐